# Error when running a spring boot integration test using powermock and junit?

Tags: spring, junit4, powermock, spring-test

Hi I am having a springboot application. while trying to run a junit spring integration test i am getting an error.

```
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.openmind.primecast.config.LoggingConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$4afbeba5]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: loader (instance of org/powermock/core/classloader/MockClassLoader) previously initiated loading for a different type with name "javax/net/SocketFactory"
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:154)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:122)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver$1.run(ConstructorResolver.java:265)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:262)
    ... 50 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: loader (instance of org/powermock/core/classloader/MockClassLoader) previously initiated loading for a different type with name "javax/net/SocketFactory"
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at org.powermock.core.classloader.MockClassLoader.loadUnmockedClass(MockClassLoader.java:262)
    at org.powermock.core.classloader.MockClassLoader.loadModifiedClass(MockClassLoader.java:206)
    at org.powermock.core.classloader.DeferSupportingClassLoader.loadClass1(DeferSupportingClassLoader.java:89)
    at org.powermock.core.classloader.DeferSupportingClassLoader.loadClass(DeferSupportingClassLoader.java:79)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at com.openmind.primecast.config.LoggingConfiguration.addLogstashAppender(LoggingConfiguration.java:66)
    at com.openmind.primecast.config.LoggingConfiguration.<init>(LoggingConfiguration.java:49)
    at com.openmind.primecast.config.LoggingConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$4afbeba5.<init>(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:142)
    ... 54 common frames omitted
```

this is my junit test class

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PowerMockIgnore({"javax.management.*", "javax.net.ssl.*"})

@SpringBootTest(classes = PrimecastApp.class)
@PowerMockRunnerDelegate(SpringRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(com.openmind.primecast.security.SecurityUtils.class)
@WithMockUser
public class CampaignResourceIntTest extends AbstractCassandraTest {

    @Test
    @WithMockUser
    public void getCsvForPerformanceNotFound() throws Exception {

        PowerMockito.mockStatic(com.openmind.primecast.security.SecurityUtils.class);
        BDDMockito.given(com.openmind.primecast.security.SecurityUtils.getCurrentUserLogin()).willReturn(Optional.of(user.getLogin()));

        UserDTO userDto = new UserDTO();
        userDto.setAccount(null);
        when(userService.getUserWithAuthoritiesByLogin(anyString())).thenReturn(userDto);

        restCampaignMockMvc.perform(get("/api/campaigns/{id}/performance/csv", UUID.randomUUID()))
            .andExpect(status().isNotFound());
    }


}
```

i have no clue . I am using this in my test @PowerMockIgnore({"javax.management.*", "javax.net.ssl.*"})

really appreciate any help 
thank you